# How to remove space between tiles in a grid

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have PNG file that contains a grid of tiles. There is a two pixel wide transparent space between each tile but I would like to remove that. I'd like their edges to be flush without a space.

Aside from manually selecting each tile and re-positioning it, is there an easier way to remove this gap in Photoshop?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Would filling in the white space with the color of the tile not work? What do these tiles look like? Does it need to shrink?

Answer (score 2):

There might be a tool, but I don't know. I thought game maker but that only imports sprite sheets, can't export them (they become single-row strips). Perhaps something like RPGmaker or similar sprite-related software?

If you end up doing it by hand, though, don't do it per tile. Do it per row/column. Instead of moving X*Y times, you'll only have to move X+Y times.